# Can effect size go beyond 1 using hedges g or cohens d in meta analysis?

Tags: metafor

i am using R metafor package to calculate effect size. hedges g is applied as my sample size is different for comparative groups.

i came across that effect size 0.9 is very strong but i am getting 1.3, i am not sure if that is right.

Answer (score 0):

There is in principle no lower/upper bound on a standardized mean difference. If the mean difference is large or the SD is small, it can get very large. However, if it gets very large (e.g., values like 5 or 10), I would start to get worried that something is off with the information provided/used (a common mistake is that standard errors of the mean are used instead of standard deviations in computing the standardized mean difference, leading to values that are way too large).